# The excelsheet was uploaded different machine i.e.,Windows or Sun solories.How can i shown the same excelsheet when user select report using Servlets

Tags: servlets

In my application,we are having two different machines i.e.,Sun Solories and window machine.User will uploaded ms-excelsheet any one machine.So,I want to display same excelsheet when i uploaded completed in the report.User wlll select report any machine at any time.So,I need how will proceseed this scenario.I am thing i will save excelsheet using clob object in oracle.But i don't its right or not?.Please give any solutions in this
scenario

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter what operating system the client or server runs as long as you treat binary files properly in the server side and the client has the necessary software installed to open the desired binary file.

First, you need to store binary data in a blob, not a clob. A clob is intended for character/text data, not for binary data. Binary data would otherwise only be malformed. Once you've fixed that, then just create a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) which gets an `InputStream` of the blob using `ResultSet#getBinaryStream()` based on a request parameter or pathinfo and then streams it to the `OutputStream` of the HTTP response along with a set of proper response headers which instructs the browser what to do with it.

For example,

```
String filename = URLDecoder.decode(request.getPathInfo().substring(1), "UTF-8");
InputStream input = getInputStreamFromDatabase(filename); // Do the JDBC job there.
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();

response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

// Now write input to output the usual way.
```

Then you can invoke it by http://example.com/context/excelservlet/filename.xls.